# Facebook messenger bot not sending messages (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've followed [this tutorial](https://abhaykashyap.com/blog/post/tutorial-how-build-facebook-messenger-bot-using-django-ngrok) to implement a Facebook Messenger bot that simply echoes what you type. It hooks up ok with Facebook, but I can't make it work beyond that and I can't find the problem. Can you please help me? This is the code so far (with minor modifications compared with the code in the tutorial).

```
class BotsView(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.GET.get('hub.verify_token') == '1111111111':
            return HttpResponse(self.request.GET.get('hub.challenge'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Error, invalid token')

    def post_facebook_message(fbid, recevied_message):           
        post_message_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<access-token>' 
        response_msg = json.dumps({"recipient":{"id":fbid}, "message":{"text":recevied_message}})
        requests.post(post_message_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},data=response_msg)
        return HttpResponse()

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return generic.View.dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Converts the text payload into a python dictionary
        incoming_message = json.loads(self.request.body)
        # Facebook recommends going through every entry since they might send
        # multiple messages in a single call during high load
        for entry in incoming_message['entry']:
            for message in entry['messaging']:
                # Check to make sure the received call is a message call
                # This might be delivery, optin, postback for other events 
                if message.has_key('message'):
                    # Print the message to the terminal
                    # pprint(message) 
                    # Assuming the sender only sends text. Non-text messages like stickers, audio, pictures
                    # are sent as attachments and must be handled accordingly. 
                    post_facebook_message(message['sender']['id'], message['message']['text'])     
        return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the entire function

```
def post_facebook_message(fbid, recevied_message): 
  ....
```

outside of the BotsView class. If you keep it within the class, it must take in "self" as its first parameter and they must be accessed within the class as

```
self.post_facebook_message(.....)
```

However, it might not be the best thing to put this function in the Django View Class.

p.s - Thanks for this, I will update the tutorial to make this point explicit.